# Recover data in a SQL table without backups

Tags: sql, data-recovery

We are having a database without backup to restore. ( we didn’t keep backups as client not having enough space in his Server). Unfortunately some data has been lost and we need to recover those.
Please provide a way of doing this.

Comment: Can be hard or impossible. First question, which dbms product are you using? (Actually, contact a professional to help you!)

Comment: Maybe on extracting lost data from transaction log. But I'd say 'bad luck'

Comment: Most likely you can't. Next time, take backups and make sure you *can* restore the database from them. I hope the client now understands that he should have payed a few bucks for storage. You can even store the backup data on a cheap external drive - it's safer than having no backup at all

Comment: @frlan The database would recover automatically if it could find the data in the log

Comment: we are using sqlserver2012

Comment: What does "some data has been lost" mean? Did a user delete the data, was a file corrupted, did a drive fault occur?

Comment: Transaktionlog -> Check for e.g. delete statement -> Use them to build up revert command aka reinsert them. Please ask a professional.

Comment: we have separate job to wipe some data. but due to error some data has deleted

Comment: @frlan Or ask the question on dba.stackexchange.com, not here. The OP **may** be able to do a [point-in-time restore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx)  to recover from accidental deletion by specifying the database itself as the backup source and selecting a point before the deletion. It's best to create a new database instead of restoring over the existing database

Comment: do you have any idea of a free tool to do this task?

Comment: You may be able to do a point-in-time restore then, assuming you haven't truncated the log or aren't using simple mode

Comment: This isn't a case where you can click a button to fix the problem. You need to know what you are doing. If you had backups, you could quickly restore to a previous state.

Comment: To put it another way, right now you need a doctor, preferably one with emergency response training. Aspirins won't help

Comment: If you still have the transactions log a tool like http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx might help you